# How many objects will be created for String?

Tags: java, string

I know that When we use String literals as given below the String object is created in String pool (if it doesn't exist).

```
String str1= "hello";
String str2= "hello";
```

In above case only one string object will be created in pool.

But, when we use new keyword it always creates a new String object in heap memory (even though there is one in String pool)

```
 String str3=new String("hello"); // here a new object will be created in heap.
```

Here, i have one confusion regarding how many objects will be created in below cases and where (pool or heap memory).

```
 1) String s="Hello";
    String s1 = new String ("Hello");

 2) String s = new String("Hello");
    String s1 = new String("Hello");

 3) String s="Hello";
    String s1=new String (s);

 4) String s1 = new String ("Hello");
    String s="Hello";
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the JRE source?

Answer (score 3):

Every invocation of new String(...) will create a new instance. You can use String.intern() to get an instance from the pool.

```
String s="Hello";
String s1 = new String ("Hello");
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(s)==System.identityHashCode(s1));


String si= new String ("Hello").intern();
String s1i = new String ("Hello").intern();
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(si)==System.identityHashCode(s1i));
```

This prints false and true

Comment: Yes, String x = new String("Hello") will create a new instance in heap, But, does it create a new String in Pool also if we don't use intern() method ??

Answer (score 1):

We can account for memory in Java’s String objects in the same way as
for any other object, except that aliasing is common for strings.

The standard String
implementation has four instance variables: a reference to a `character array (8 bytes)`
and `three int values (4 bytes each)`. The first int value is an offset into the character array;
the second is a count (the string length).

[image: String Object]

In terms of the instance variable names in
the drawing on the figure, the string that is represented consists of the characters
value[offset] through value[offset + count - 1]. The third int value in String
objects is a `hash code` that saves recomputation in certain circumstances.

Therefore, each String object uses a total of **40 bytes (16 bytes for
object overhead plus 4 bytes for each of the three int instance variables plus 8 bytes for
the array reference plus 4 bytes of padding).**

This space requirement is in addition to
the space needed for the characters themselves, which are in the array. The space needed
for the characters is accounted for separately because the char array is often shared
among strings. Since String objects are immutable, this arrangement allows the implementation
to save memory when String objects have the same underlying value[].
String values and substrings.

**A String of length N typically uses 40 bytes (for the
String object) plus 24  2N bytes (for the array that contains the characters) for a
total of 64 + 2N bytes.** But it is typical in string processing to work with substrings, and
Java’s representation is meant to allow us to do so without having to make copies of the string's characters!

> Source: Algorithms 4th Edition

Comment: Your description is outdated, they changed the `String` representation in Java 7. There is no `offset` and `count` any more and strings cannot share parts of their conent (substrings) any more.

Comment: @MartinS Then please do edit it to keep it correct ! :)

Answer (score 0):

**How many objects are being created for your examples?**

```
 1) 4        
 2) 4        
 3) 3        
 4) 4
```

Note that each `String` object contains a `char`-array with the content of the string. So when creating a new `String` you actually create two objects.

**1) 2) and 4)**

Each line in your examples either creates a `String` in the pool which contains a `char`-array (therefore we have two objects) or create a new `String` which - again - contains a `char`-array. Note that in neither of these examples the strings share any of the content.

**3)**

This example is different since we use the first `String` (2 objects) to create the second `String`. In this case the second `String` will be a new object **but** it will use the very same `char`-array as the first one, therefore not creating a new one. This leads to a total of only 3 objects instead of 4.

**One more example**

```
String s1 = "Hello";
String s2 = "Hello";
```

In this case we will have only 2 objects, since `s1` and `s2` will both point to the same `String` object in the pool with the same `char`-array.